# Dynamic Charts with Variables on Two Axes

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-2010, range

I'm trying to utilize the Range Names feature in Excel to create a chart that will automatically update once new data is appended. I've successfully done this with two variables (i.e. Date and Temperature) but I'm unable to get it working with 3 or more variables.

Within a tab titled, 'Dynamic', I have a `Date` (value in A1) column with these values: `4/1/2013, 4/2/2013, 4/3/2013, 4/4/2013, 4/5/2013` (Value in A6).

I also have a `Temperature` (value in B1) column with these values: `55, 60, 62, 65, 61` (Value in B6).

Within the Name Manager (within Formulas tab) I created a Named Range with a Name of "Date" and a Refers to value of:

`=OFFSET(Dynamic!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA(Dynamic!$A:$A)-1)`

I created another Named Range with a Name of "Temperatues" and a Refers to value of:

`=OFFSET(Dynamic!$B$2,0,0,COUNTA(Dynamic!$B:$B)-1)`

I then selected the range A1:B6 and inserted a Clustered Column chart. Clicking on one of the bars yields this formula:

`=SERIES(Dynamic!$B$1,Dynamic!$A$2:$A$6,Dynamic!$B$2:$B$6,1)`

If I insert my Named Ranges in the above formula like so:

`=SERIES(Dynamic!$B$1,Dynamic!Date,Dynamic!Temperatures,1)`

and it will allow me to add a new row of data and it automatically updates the chart.

This is great! But when I attempt to add another variable I can't get it to work. I add `Rainfall` (value in C1) to the spreadsheet with these values: `1, 2, 0.5, 0, 1`. I create a Name Range with a Name of "Rainfall" and a Refers to value of:

`=OFFSET(Dynamic!$C$2,0,0,COUNTA(Dynamic!$C:$C)-1)`

I then select A1:C6, insert a Clustered Column chart. Clicking on one of the Temperature bars I change the formula to:

`=SERIES(Dynamic!$B$1,Dynamic!Date,Dynamic!Temperatures,1)`

When I attempt to change the formula for the Rainfall bars I try this:

`=SERIES(Dynamic!$C$1,Dynamic!Date,Dynamic!Rainfall,2)`

but when I hit enter it won't do anything. So, I'm left with a chart that won't update automatically.

Assuming I could get this to work, I'd like to move the Rainfall data onto a secondary axis and change the chart type to a line chart (so that it all fits nicely onto the same chart area).

**Can you tell me what I need to do to get this example to work?** Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get this to work either, using the SERIES formula. Then again, I suppose it is considered an undocumented feature.

However, if you edit using the `Select Data` dialog then it works.